# trying to understand how a line of code got added in git

Tags: git, github

In the 1.0 branch of https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib there's a file - [phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commits/1.0/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php).

Commit `bfba3db` [removed the `setKey()` method from that file](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/bfba3db1a70dc234b87fbca7d382607ae378fed1#diff-1047d59d38adbbe65d3b99d35499d07e4f6250f52b74b7e39bb677fd7cbbbef5L308). That method remained removed in [the next commit](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/d91158f6ef741f7f548091b0ee32ecac33f0207f/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php) (`d91158f`) but then that method is [back in the file in the commit after that](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/19229ed22425d4796a740fae2f354e0db932c839/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php#L308) (`19229ed`) even tho that commit [does not appear to re-add that method](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/19229ed22425d4796a740fae2f354e0db932c839#diff-1047d59d38adbbe65d3b99d35499d07e4f6250f52b74b7e39bb677fd7cbbbef5).

So how did the `setKey()` method get added back into that file?

I thought maybe github.com wasn't showing merge commits when viewing file history but there [are no commits, merge or otherwise, between the commit d91158f and 19229ed](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commits/1.0?after=320c43a4a0ff8838dc810c61b90e7b62d3c0d060+524&branch=1.0&qualified_name=refs%2Fheads%2F1.0) so that theory is clearly bunk.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even better, view branches with `gitk --all &`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub interface lies about branches. Commit `bfba3db` is on a different branch. `d91158f` is not the next, the next is `86910352`. The branch was merged into `1.0` at commit `666092c8`. But commit `19229ed2` is again on a different branch that was branched off from `1.0` before `666092c8` so that branch contains the code for `setKey()`.

My advice is to clone the branch using `git clone -b 1.0 https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib.git` and view branches and commits using `git log --decorate --graph`. This is the interesting part of the graph:

```
| * commit 19229ed2
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Mon Oct 5 10:08:46 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     phpDoc changes
| |   
* |   commit 666092c8
|\ \  Merge: c0e42ad7 5f1ff099
| |/  Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
|/|   Date:   Mon Oct 12 22:59:46 2015 -0500
| |   
| |       Merge branch 'getkeylength' into 1.0
| | 
| * commit 5f1ff099
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Mon Oct 12 22:52:56 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     Crypt/Base: one more cs update
| | 
| * commit d91158f6
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Sun Oct 4 21:06:17 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     rename key_size -> key_length
| | 
| * commit 27034825
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Sun Oct 4 16:29:48 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     cs changes per bantu
| | 
| * commit 86910352
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Thu Sep 24 09:29:00 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     Crypt/Base: add getBlockLength() method
| | 
| * commit bfba3db1
| | Author: terrafrost <terrafrost@php.net>
| | Date:   Thu Sep 17 10:46:45 2015 -0500
| | 
| |     Crypt: make it so the key length can be explicitly set for all ciphers
```

Comment: `git log` has a ton of options and defaults for targeting results, I'd say `-S`, `-m`, `-p` and `--full-history` all seem useful here.